# Show that the collection $\{ M_x:x\in S\}$ has finite intersection property

Tags: banach-spaces

Currently I am reading the book '[Isometries in Banach Spaces: Vector-valued Function Spaces and Operator Spaces, Volume Two](https://www.crcpress.com/Isometries-in-Banach-Spaces-Vector-valued-Function-Spaces-and-Operator/Fleming-Jamison/p/book/9781584883869)', Chapter $7,$ page $6.$

**Definitions**: A $T$-set is a subset $S$ of a Banach space $X$ with the property that for any finite collection $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in S$ such that 
$$\left\Vert \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right\Vert = \sum_{j=1}^n \|x_j\|,$$
and such that $S$ is maximal with respect to this property.

For any $x\in X,$ let $M_x :=\{ y^*\in B(X^*):y^*(x)=\|x\| \}$ where $B(X^*) = \{ y^*: \|y^*\| \leq 1 \}.$

> **Question**: Because of the norm additive property of the $T$-set $S,$ **the collection $\{ M_x:x\in S \}$ has the finite intersection property.**

It suffices to show that it (bold statement) for $x_1,x_2\in S,$ as it can be generalized easily.

Suppose that $x_1,x_2\in S.$ 
We want to show that there exists $z^*\in M_{x_1}\cap M_{x_2}$ such that $\|z^*\|\leq 1, z^*(x_1)=\|x_1\|$ and $z^*(x_2)=\|x_2\|.$

Since $x_1,x_2 \in S,$ we have $\|x_1+x_2\| = \|x_1\| + \|x_2\|.$
Then there exists $z_1^*,z_2^*$ and $z_3^*$ such that 
$$z_3^*(x_1+x_2) = z_1^*(x_1)+z_2^*(x_2).$$
However, I fail to show that $z_1^*=z_2^*=z_3^*.$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x_1,x_2\in S$. There exists a norm-$1$ functional $z^{*}$ such that
$$z^*(x_1+x_2)=|\!|x_1+x_2|\!|=|\!|x_1|\!|+|\!|x_2|\!|\enspace\enspace(1)$$
Where the second equality follows from the assumption that $x_1,x_2\in S$. Since $z^*$ has norm $1$ we have $z^*(x_1)\leq|\!|x_1|\!|$ and $z^*(x_2)\leq |\!|x_2|\!|$, and we must have equalities in both these inequalities or else $(1)$ will not hold. This means that $z^*\in M_{x_1}\cap M_{x_2}$.